# spaCy v3 [E930] training configuration file of `el_core_news_lg`

Tags: config, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I want to further train the Greek model of spaCy `el_core_news_lg` for the NER task with the training configuration file that is introduced in spaCy v3.

`spacy train` command throws the error:

`[E923] It looks like there is no proper sample data to initialize the Model of component 'tok2vec'. To check your input data paths and annotation, run: python -m spacy debug data config.cfg`

When I run `spacy debug data` as the error suggests, I get the error:

`[E930] Received invalid get_examples callback in Tok2Vec.initialize. Expected function that returns an iterable of Example objects but got: []`

Any ideas?